# Can't submit edit because question with same title already exists?

Tags: bug, edits, title

How does the original author of a question get to create a duplicate title but an editor of the question (who didn't even change the title) gets told that it can't be edited because a question of that title already exists?  The question under debate is now called [Segmentation Fault (core dumped)...BMH Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263759/), where I added the 'BMH Algorithm' to get past the uniqueness filter.  (Don't get me wrong; the title wasn't great — but it was acceptable when the question was asked, so why wasn't acceptable when the question was edited?)

There's a question about this from January 2012 with 'status-completed'.  If it was fixed back then, it is now unfixed again.

Comment: If it's an old question, it could have occurred before that restriction was put into place. It didn't always exist.

Comment: @animuson: The question (which I've now identified) was under an hour old when I tried to edit its body ... I doubt if that's the reason.

Comment: Hmm, that looks like it might have something to do with periods at the end... The [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271820/segmentation-fault-core-dumped) doesn't have them.

Comment: It's quite possible punctuation like that is ignored to prevent people just adding periods to create uniqueness. But only when someone edits? Sounds fishy to me.