# editing a post gives me an "A question with that title already exists" error part 2

Tags: bug, edits

So I was editing [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067199/what-am-i-doing-wrong) and what I was doing was very simple.  I was moving the problem description before the code.

I tried to submit the edit, but it told me that

`A question with that title already exists`

[image]

The following posts seem to suggest that we use to have this issue, but it has since been fixed.

[Can't submit edit because question with same title already exists?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170553/cant-submit-edit-because-question-with-same-title-already-exists)

[I can't edit a question when the title already exists, but I can ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106911/i-cant-edit-a-question-when-the-title-already-exists-but-i-can-ask)

But apparently the bug is back.

PS, I know that I could change the title, but the bug still exists.  the user was still able to submit a question with that title.

Comment: You missed an opportunity there - you should have used "Can't submit edit because question with same title already exists??" as your title to illustrate the issue

Comment: I got it as well.

Comment: This bug still exist. The problem is why user can post the question on first place. Because for the editer is very confusing see that message when he isnt changing the title.